# How to detect when an API request will ask for Basic Auth in Chrome?

Tags: api, google-chrome, authentication, google-chrome-extension, authorization

When I make an API request with JavaScript in Chrome and it requires basic auth (username/password), Chrome automatically opens a popup so the user can enter their credentials. After entering it once, it won't ask again for a while until the username/password is removed from the Chrome cache.

Is there any way to detect that this popup will appear before making a request (ex: check whether or not the basic auth for this API endpoint is cached)? I want to give a short message before the popup appears so the user understands why they need to sign in again.

[image: Text]

Comment: To clarify; the reason I am using the built in Chrome popup instead of creating a custom HTML form and letting the user enter in the details there is that I am building a local chrome extension. Thus, I can't store the username/password because it is unsafe to do so in local storage, and I don't plan on creating a database just to store username/passwords. It's easier to use the Chrome popup because it automatically caches the username/password for me and I don't have to store it anywhere.

Comment: I am actually having a similar issue. I am calling a REST API on server X. When I use Internet Explorer it works properly, don't ask for credentials, when I use Chrome, it asks for credentials the first time you try to call the API, for subsequently requests it doesn't. 
Did you manage to sort it out?